# ClassNotFoundException - HeyZapAd

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, heyzap

I'm trying to use HeyZapAd SDK in my project but it's not working. When I look at the logcat, I see that the class files of the SDK are not found and many of them are obfuscated. This issue persists even if I disable Proguard.

**UPDATE:** I've created a new Project in Android Studio and added the HeyZap SDK and I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong while adding the SDK to my project or the issue is with the SDK!

Kindly, look at my app/build.gradle and some part of the logcat.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.animalsdrawingbook.android"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//    compile project(':SupportLibrary')
    implementation project(':SupportLibrary-release')
//    compile project(':infinitecycleviewpager')
//    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
//    compile 'com.github.Andreu35:BrushView:v.1.0'
    implementation 'com.fyber:fairbid:9.56.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kila.apprater_dialog.lars:apprater-dialog:1.0.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Here's the logcat

```
2019-07-11 08:44:14.025 1842-1842/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-YRbWpN3NP24S4xy4YKzMyw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-07-11 08:44:14.030 1586-1645/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
2019-07-11 08:44:14.029 1842-1857/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED dat=package:com.animalsdrawingbook.android flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.photos/.account.full.FetchAccountPropertiesAppUpgradeBroadcastReceiver
2019-07-11 08:44:14.066 1842-1842/? E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-YRbWpN3NP24S4xy4YKzMyw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.heyzap.sdk.a.a.a$a>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/adcolony/sdk/AdColonyInterstitialListener;
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at com.heyzap.mediation.a.c com.heyzap.mediation.a.c.a(java.lang.Class) (SourceFile:292)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.mediation.d$1.run() (SourceFile:2055)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.344 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:458)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.345 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.347 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.347 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.347 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.347 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.347 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-x2pjcInqNV9lazUhBLhW_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-x2pjcInqNV9lazUhBLhW_w==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at com.heyzap.mediation.a.c com.heyzap.mediation.a.c.a(java.lang.Class) (SourceFile:292)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.mediation.d$1.run() (SourceFile:2055)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:458)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.349 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.350 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.heyzap.sdk.a.a.a$a>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/adcolony/sdk/AdColonyInterstitialListener;
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at com.heyzap.mediation.a.c com.heyzap.mediation.a.c.a(java.lang.Class) (SourceFile:292)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.mediation.d$1.run() (SourceFile:2055)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:458)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-x2pjcInqNV9lazUhBLhW_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.animalsdrawingbook.android-x2pjcInqNV9lazUhBLhW_w==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.351 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:343)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at com.heyzap.mediation.a.c com.heyzap.mediation.a.c.a(java.lang.Class) (SourceFile:292)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.mediation.d$1.run() (SourceFile:2055)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.352 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.353 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void com.heyzap.common.c.l.run() (SourceFile:26)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at java.lang.Object java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() (Executors.java:458)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() (FutureTask.java:266)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run() (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2019-07-11 08:44:16.354 25959-26017/com.animalsdrawingbook.android I/ingbook.androi:     at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: where you added "android.support.v4.*"  in gradle ?  remove this " implementation project(':SupportLibrary-release')" and add proper support library.

Comment: Actually, this is someone else's project I'm working on. In the "SupportLibrary-release" module, there are other classes which is being used. But I don't think it's the issue. Because I've just created a new Android Studio project and integrated the HeyZap SDK to test and I'm getting the same errors!